# does Parse.com have a limit on the number of channels that can be created?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, push-notification

Is there any limit on the number of channels that can be created on Parse ? for example if i were to build a group chat application and each group resembles a channel, how many such groups can be created ? Is there any upper limit ?

Also is there a limit on the number of people who can subscribe to a particular channel ?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is already answered on forum of Parse.com .

**Q. Is there a limit on the number of channels an Installation can be subscribed to?**

**Ans :** There's no specific limit on how many channels an installation can subscribe to, other than the max size of the Installation object itself which is 128 KB. If you're worried about using too many channels, it's likely that your problem is better solved with advanced targeting.

**Q. What is the max number of channels one can pass in for Push Notifications using REST API?**

**Ans :** There's no hard limit on how many channels you can specify. You can also use advanced targeting in place of channels for finer grained control.

Here provided links for both the queries on forum :

https://www.parse.com/questions/what-is-the-max-number-of-channels-one-can-pass-in-for-push-notifications-using-rest-api

https://www.parse.com/questions/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-channels-an-installation-can-be-subscribed-to

Hope it helps.

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there's no limit on channels.

I wanted to let you know that you can now push directly to a user on iOS, provided you are sending notifications via the REST API. This blog post has more information: http://blog.parse.com/2012/07/06/pushing-to-queries-in-ios/ . You can also target push notifications by device token, geographical region, or according to any other data that you store on a per-device basis.

For your info :

> The channel name must start with a letter and contain only letters,
>   numbers, dashes, and underscores.